# Eclipse won't run using sudo

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, sudo

I'm running eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu 12.04 and it runs fine normally. I'm trying to get it to use the var/www web server directory for some php development though and since that's owned by root I need to run eclipse using sudo. Whenever I do I get the error:

```
!SESSION 2013-10-31 00:54:22.009 ---------------------------------- -------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-10-31 00:54:23.055
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
no swt-gtk in java.library.path
Can't load library: /root/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
Can't load library: /root/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

I have the libswt-gtk files stored at /home/user/.swt/lib/linux/ and also at /usr/lib/jni/ but I assume for the error log that eclipse is looking for them in the root file directory itself? How do I change this path?

Comment: Have you considered changing the permissions on /var/www (or adding your user to the group that owns /var/www/) instead of running an arbitrary program as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Making a symbolic link in your root directory to point to the one in your user directory.

```
ln -s /home/user/.swt/ /root/.swt/
```

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly for UIs there's [gksudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo). Not sure if it comes pre-installed in the latest versions of Ubuntu, so you might need to `sudo apt-get install gksudo` first